# logging.file.max-history is not working in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, logback

I want to delete log files automatically in my Spring Boot apps and use the following settings:

```
logging:
  file:
    name: './logs/application.log'
    max-size: 10KB # for test purpose keep small
    max-history: 5
```

Here is the documentation page:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

However, neither `max-size` nor `max-history` is working and new log files are created more than 5.

I am not sure if I have to set `logback` config, but if I have to, is the following approach suitable for deleting log files automatically?

https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/logback-rolling-files-example

Comment: Just to be clear: `max-history` determines not the amount of files but the number of days to keep the logs, so in your case everything older than 5 days will be deleted.

Comment: Hmm, good information. Then I have 2 questions. **1.** Will the delete operation occurs only initializing the app?

Comment: **2.** Do you have an idea how can I solve this problem? O I have to use `max-history` and wait the log files to be deleted by older than x days ?

Comment: It will do so, if you set `logging.file.clean-history-on-start=true`

Comment: If I do not do this? When will it clean or what is the meaning of that setting (max-history)?

Comment: You might make use of `logging.file.total-size-cap` (instead of `max-size`) this will make sure your total size of all log files won't exceed the limit and delete the oldest files _on demand_ (`max-size` is for **one** file)

Comment: @leun4m Thank you so much. Could you pls post an example by using these properties? Because there are several properties that has name with file and I am not sure the correct place for yml. Any idea?

Comment: I tried but none of them is worked (as I said, using wrong hyerarchy). Any example usage pls?

Comment: I used all of them below `logging` setting, but not working: `  file.max-size: 5KB # Roll the log file when it reaches max size
  file.max-history: 1
  file.total-size-cap: 3
  file.clean-history-on-start: true`

Comment: I used all of them below `logging` setting, but not working: `file.max-size: 5KB # Roll the log file when it reaches max size
  file.max-history: 1
  file.total-size-cap: 3
  file.clean-history-on-start: true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is misunderstanding about what the properties mean.

According to https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/logback-rolling-files-example#

`max-size`

Sets the maximum size of one file, if the file size gets exceeded a new file will be created.

`max-history`

Sets the number of days the logs are kept. Older files will be deleted, if `clean-history-on-start` is set to true.

`total-size-cap`

Sets the limit for the total size of all log files.

**You may instead consider this:**

```yaml
logging:
  file:
    name: './logs/application.log'
    max-history: 5
    total-size-cap: 10KB
    clean-history-on-start: true
```